# Regex Java allow number, letters, special char (some)

Tags: java, regex

I have a file name, lets say upload 23_3.jpg. I would like to allow only letters, (.) period, (-) hypen sign, underscore (_)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9_.]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(i.getFileName());

boolean specialCharFound = m.find(); //this will return true if any other characters are found
```

^ means not a-z, letters and I added _ and ., but it doesn't work. Any idea how to add '_' '.' '-' characters?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use this tool: https://regex101.com/

Comment: the ^ refers to the whole regex, why would you need it anyway? As for the hyphen, `-`, it must be the first in a class

Comment: You should provide some examples of valid and invalid names. Are `...`, `---`, `___`, `.-_`, `-._` also valid names?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add those characters at the end of the character class.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9_. -]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: I tried but it says Boolean is false when the file name has _ in it

Comment: @user3508506 What's the filename that it doesn't work with?

Comment: @user3508506 Also, false means that no unallowed character was found.

Comment: "ucal 213_334.jpg" comes out as true despite having a valid character . and _

Comment: . is a special charactor in regexp. you'll have to mask it. Your expression should look like "[^a-z0-9_\\.-]"

Comment: i removed space now it's false. So how do you add space to valid char? just blank? thanks like this Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9_.- ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Comment: `.` does not have to be backslash-escaped inside a set in square brackets. `-` must appear as either the first or last character, so that it is not part of a range.

Comment: Seems like in java space is space [^a-z0-9_. -]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what '^" is doing.  I think  you want to remove it.

You need to escape the special characters with a slash.  I think only '.' should be escaped and - and _ don't need escaping.

Try:
[a-z0-9_-.]

Perhaps - and _ have an issue with CASE_INSENSITIVE, consider Pattern.UNICODE_CASE.  Or consider no case flag and add a A-Z.

Try:
[A-Za-z0-9_-.], no CASE_INSENTIVE

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pattern.compile("[\\w\\s.-]+")` **and** `m.matches()`:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\s.-]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(i.getFileName());
boolean isValid = m.matches();
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/b2UvLT/1).

**Explanation**

```java
[\w\s.-]+                any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " "), '.', '-' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```